Error "Cannot perform this task after onSavedInstanceState" when adding fragment in onRestart() method in Android
I'm working on an Android app where I'm checking if the user has granted camera permissions in the onCreate() and onRestart() methods. If permissions are granted, I begin a fragment transaction to add a camera fragment using the following code:
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.cameraFragment, CameraFragment.class, null)
.commit();

If permission is not granted, I show a rationale and navigate the user to the app settings. when coming back from the app settings, in the onRestart() I also check if the user has granted camera permissions, if not I show the rationale message again and take the user to the app settings. If the permission has been granted, and coming back from the app settings, I am trying to begin a fragment transaction to add a camera fragment. but here is the place I am getting this error Cannot perform this task after onSavedInstanceState and here is the exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                                               
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1632)                                                                                                   
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1672)                                                                                                    
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:341)                                                                                                    
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:306)                                                                                                        
at com.example.democamapp.Main.CameraActivity.beginArFragmentTransaction
(CameraActivity.java:144)                                                                                                        
at com.example.democamapp.Main.CameraActivity.checkAndRequestRuntimePermission
(CameraActivity.java:78)                                                                                                     
at com.example.democamapp.Main.CameraActivity.onRestart(CameraActivity.java:54)                                                                                                      
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestart(Instrumentation.java:1445)                                                                                                      
at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:8315)                                                                                                   
at android.app.ActivityThread.performRestartActivity(ActivityThread.java:5501)                                                                                                       
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence
(TransactionExecutor.java:243)                                                                                                       
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath
(TransactionExecutor.java:201)                                                                                                   
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState
(TransactionExecutor.java:173)                                                                                                       
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute
(TransactionExecutor.java:97)                                                                                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)                                                                                                      
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                                                                                      
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)                                                                                                       
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)                                                                                                     
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                        
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)                                                                                                     
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)

What is the best way to handle fragment transactions after checking permissions in onRestart() without encountering this error?
